# How do I use the Materialize Mediabox component

Tags: javascript, materialize

I would like to implement the slider on this page: http://materializecss.com/media.html

I copied the initialization script with my chosen input as so:

```
<script>
var elem = document.querySelector('.slider');
var instance = M.Slider.init(elem, inDuration:180);
</script>
```

And pasted at the end of my body. The page does not display anything even when using the example html code provided. What I am doing wrong? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are directly giving value to the options parameter.
Instead of that, first declare that option, give it a desired value, and then use it in the function, like this:

```
var elem = document.querySelector('.slider');
var height = 500;
let inDuration = 1800;
var instance = M.Slider.init(elem, inDuration);
```

If you want to see a working demo, you can find it on [my codepen](https://codepen.io/pandaa/pen/geqLNN).